# Returning promise data to the calling function

Tags: javascript, promise

```
let func1 = function() {
   return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        let someVal = 5;
        if (condition) {
            resolve(someVal);
        }
        else {
            reject('error occured');
        }
   });
}

let callingFunction = function() {
    func1().then((res) => {
        console.log("result",res); /* want to return res to the callingFunction */
        return res; /* doesn't work as it returns to the .then not to the callingFunction I guess. */
    });
}

let finalData = callingFunction();
```

Is it feasible to send the result from `.then` block of promise to callingFunction so that I get result in finalData?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what exactly you are trying to achieve? It's not really clear from the description .. a bit of context would go a long way.

Comment: I want to return the value when the promise is fulfilled to the callingFunction and I  need this value to be used somewhere else say template or some other function.

Comment: Doesnot return to the callingFunction it return to .then I guess.Check the edit.

Comment: Please add language tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let callingFunction = function() {
  return func1().then((res) => {
    console.log("result",res)
    return res
  })
}
callingFunction().then((res) => {
  let finalData = res
})
```

Comment: Although this code may provide the answer, it is more helpful to explain what is different and why that makes the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that promise is an asynchronous operation, hence `let finalData = callingFunction();` evaluates to *undefined*. If you'd like to use promise's result in `callingFunction()`, just pass `res` as an argument to it like this:

```
let func1 = function() {
   return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        let someVal = 5;
        if (condition) {
            resolve(someVal);
        }
        else {
            reject('error occured');
        }
   });
}

func1().then((res) => {
    console.log("result",res); /* want to return res to the callingFunction */
    callingFunction(res);
  });
```